# How do I middle-click paste text into curses text-gui apps (i.e. aptitude)?

Tags: terminal, gnome, aptitude

I have a Gnome desktop and I use the standard Terminal (gnome-terminal). I can middle-click paste text into the terminal but not when running [Aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) - a curses-based UI.

Just now, I realized that's [Aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) is actually click-able. In the terminal! That's probably related to the inability to middle-click paste.

I don't need click-ability but I need to paste via middle-click (e.g. into [Aptitude's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) search field). How to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking?

Comment: @Daniel, That works. But that will not save me time. I need the middle-click paste to work.

Comment: Have you tried Shift+click?

Comment: @grawity, you made my day :)

Answer (score 6):

- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you right-click.
- Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: Very helpful!  Now I am curious: Is holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> when selecting text handled by the ncurses app or the terminal emulator?  (I am using KDE konsole.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ctrl+shift+c* and *ctrl+shift+V* to copy and paste in a few terminal emulators, such as gnome-terminal.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-V pastes from _clipboard_, while middle-click uses _primary selection_.